# How to load WPF treeview resources from another assembly using MEF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro, resourcedictionary

I'm creating a WPF application which loads its plugin using MEF.
How can I include resources from another assembly I'm loading using MEF?
Specifically I want to create an HierarchicalDataTemplate in external assembly and load it to a Treeview.Resources dynamically when composing the application on start.
Is something like this possible?

I'm using Caliburn.Micro if it matters but I'm sure the question applies to general WPF applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it at the end.
Because Caliburn.Micro doesn't work properly if you use MEF's DirectoryCatalog to load your assemblies I had to do it manually. Bellow is the simplified part of the code that does it and loads the ResourceDictionary contained in the separate **resources.xaml** file.

```
FileInfo[] filesInfo = new DirectoryInfo(pluginPath).GetFiles("*.dll");
AssemblySource.Instance.AddRange(filesInfo.Select(fileInfo => Assembly.LoadFrom(fileInfo.FullName)));

// load resources from plugins
var dictionaries = App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries;
dictionaries.Clear();

foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in filesInfo)
{
    string assemblyName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileInfo.Name);
    string uriString = assemblyName + @";component/resources.xaml";

    try
    {
        dictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri(uriString, UriKind.Relative) });
    }
    catch
    {
        // do some logging
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to load static resources you should load the resource before loading the main window.
If you try to load dynamic resources you should load the resource before loading the view that uses the resource.

Any way you should add a reference to the resource by adding it to the Wpf Application merge dictionary while bootstrapping.

```
//On the bootstrapper add the following code
 ResourceDictionary rd = new ResourceDictionary
                                {
                                    Source =
                                        new Uri(
                                            "pack://application:,,,/DllName;component/Themes/ResourceName.xaml",
                                            UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
                                };


Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd);
```

Comment: Thanks Eli. But how do I tell my TreeView in my main view to use HierarchicalDataTemplate I loaded?

Comment: In the loaded assembly define a resource dictionary with your HierarchicalDataTemplate. The template should not have a key only DataType.  ex: <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type: YourDataType}"> while the application is loaded it will search for the template locally and in the end at the application resources.

Comment: Thanks again. You've put me in the right direction.